# Stop event propogation for AutoPostBack Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

We have two checkboxes inside an UpdatePanel with `AutoPostBack="true"`

```
<asp:CheckBox  ID="IsCompanyEnabled" runat="server" 
            AutoPostBack="true"
            Checked="false" 
            CssClass="agentcompany" 
            Text="COMPANY" />
<asp:CheckBox  ID="IsCompanyNotDetermined" runat="server" 
            AutoPostBack="true"
            Checked="false" 
            CssClass="agenttobedetermined" 
            Text="TO BE DETERMINED" />
```

On clicking these CheckBoxes the CheckedChanged event will fire. All is well.

Now, we have another JavaScript function that acts on the same CheckBoxes

```
function SetEmployeeDetails(selectedPanel) {

    var panel_id = "#" + selectedPanel;
    var container = $(panel_id);
    container.find(".agentcompany").find(":checkbox").prop('checked', false); //problem zone
    container.find(".agenttobedetermined").find(":checkbox").prop('checked', false); //problem zone
    //$("#popup_dialog").dialog("close");
    return false;
}
```

The problem happens in this scenario.

1. Suppose the `Company CheckBox` is checked first.
2. Then I trigger the JavaScript function, it un-checks the `Company CheckBox` after overwriting the effect of the `Company CheckBox` checked event.
3. Now, when I click the Save button on the form, the `IsCompanyEnabled_CheckChanged` event would trigger before `SaveButton_Click` event triggers.

That pretty much messes up all my code flow. I dont want the `IsCompanyEnabled_CheckedChanged` triggered again. How can I overcome this problem?

Is there a way to ask the CheckBoxes from the JavaScript function to `event.stopPropogation`?

Comment: You have no choice here (selection, xxxxchanged events will be triggered before the click event). If possible change your code-design to avoid chckbox postback & CheckedChange handlers.

Comment: @AVD: maintaining code... too big to alter...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)() ?

```
 container.find(".agentcompany").find(":checkbox")
  .click(function(event){
      event.stopPropagation();
  });
```

Comment: no luck. i am going for a big rewrite. i don't see any way out. thanks for the help.